# Using xlsxwriter to create charts from specified cells

Tags: excel, python-3.x, charts, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Alright so I am rather new to excel as a whole and was asked to write a script to take some data from a database and make a sheet out of it. Which I did, now they have asked that I add graphs to display this data in an even easier format because you know scope creep and all. Anyways I am attempting to create a pie graph that references two specific cells from a separate sheet that are not next to each other. I can get it to chart out a range from everything between those two cells but I need it to specifically only use the cells I provide.

```
executive = book.add_worksheet("Executive Summary")
yesterday_chart = book.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})
yesterday_chart.add_series({'name': 'Yesterdays Installs',
                            'values': '=(\'Total Counts\'!$B$2,\'Total Counts\'!$J$2)',
                            'points': [
                                {'fill': {'color': 'green'}},
                                {'fill': {'color': 'red'}},
                            ],
                            })
```

This is what I currently have in place which creates two points but no data populated in them. I need it to chart out cells B2 and J2 from a sheet called Total Counts. Thanks in advance for your assistance in saving my sanity.

Edit: Adding more of the code and showing output.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import xlsxwriter

book = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Testing.xlsx")

counts = book.add_worksheet("Total Counts")
r = 0
c = 0
counts.write(0, 0, "Total Installed to date")
counts.write(0, 1, "Installed Yesterday")
counts.write(0, 2, " Missed Yesterday")
counts.write(0, 3, "Scheduled Yesterday")

executive = book.add_worksheet("Executive Summary")
yesterday_chart = book.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

r += 1
counts.write(r, c, "100")
counts.set_column(c, c, len("Total Installed to date"))
c += 1
counts.write(r, c, "25")
counts.set_column(c, c, len("Installed Yesterday"))
c += 1
counts.write(r, c, "5")
counts.set_column(c, c, len("Missed Yesterday"))
c += 1
counts.write(r, c, "30")
counts.set_column(c, c, len("Scheduled Yesterday"))
c = 0

yesterday_chart.add_series({'name': 'Yesterdays Installs',
                            'values': "=('Total Counts'!$D$2,'Total Counts'!$B$2)",
                            'points': [
                                {'fill': {'color': 'green'}},
                                {'fill': {'color': 'red'}},
                            ],
                            })

executive.insert_chart(0, 0, yesterday_chart)



book.close()
```

[image: Total sheet]

[image: Output from graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax should work. Perhaps post a fuller working example so we can see what the problem is.

In the meantime, here is a working example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Total Counts')

# Create a new Chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

# Write some data to add to plot on the chart.
worksheet.write_column('A1', [2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

# Add a data series bases on some points.
chart.add_series({'values': "=('Total Counts'!$A$1,'Total Counts'!$A$3)"})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C3', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I have added more of the code as requested and attached an image. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong lol. Thanks for looking it over.

Comment: The additional code you posted doesn't help clarify the problem. You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like I did.

Comment: But if I had to guess I would say that there isn't any data in cells B2 and J2.

Comment: Alright I have added as requested but those cells do contain data. I can get it to work if I get the whole range between B2 and J2 but when I try to specify only those two it fails. Thanks again for the help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated example. The issue is that the chart data are strings and not numbers. Remove the quotes around "100", "25", etc., and the example will work. In Excel chart data must be numbers.

Comment: Sigh I knew it would be something stupid I overlooked. Thank you so much for pointing that out.